# Can Graphite chart an average value from multiple sources?

Tags: graphite, grafana

Let's say, we collect NTP-offset statistics from 500 servers. Each is known to Graphite as `stats.`*hostname*`.ntpstats.offset`.

I'd like my chart to show two curves:

- A particular host's offset (easy)
- The average of all hosts (with or without the one host above)

Can this be done? If not with Graphite, how about Grafana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a wildcard:

`avg(stats.*.ntpstats.offset)`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any idea, why `avg(abs(stats.*.ntpstats.offset))` does not work, though? I get a `KeyError`-exception from Graphite...